Podman: how to reach external service on localhost from container
I have 4.9.3 version of podman.
I use docker-compose to up one of services from what I'm trying to call external service on my localhost/127.0.0.1 but I'm getting connection refused all that time
Docker compose file looks like:
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    restart: always
    hostname: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672

  custom-service:
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - postgres
    image: my_custom_image
    ports:
      - 8071:8071
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: development
      custom_service.jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://host.containers.internal:5432/postgres
      external.url: http://host.containers.internal:8085

volumes:
  postgres:
    driver: local


As it was suggested to in some links I tried to use for my custom service in docker-compose file:
network_mode: "slirp4netns:allow_host_loopback=true"

and to use host.containers.internal instead localhost. This configuration I also used in my localhost application based on quarkus like:
quarkus:
  http:
    host: host.containers.internal
    port: 8085

All that time when my internal service custom-service from docker container tries to get external.url it gets Connect to http://host.containers.internal:8085 failed: Connection refused
I also checked my host in /ect/hosts and tried to change variable of host.containers.internal because there was no this variable before. I tried different values like:
127.0.0.1 host.containers.internal
It didn't work for me even it's possible to call http://host.containers.internal:8085 directly and I see some UI view. it's running and working but it's impossible to get it from docker container
OS: Windows 11
Docker version 25.0.4-rd
